# Host Blazor component in Avalonia

Tags: c#, blazor, avaloniaui

I'm trying to host a Blazor component in an Avalonia application using a [WebView](https://github.com/OutSystems/WebView).

I have a Blazor project with the following class:

```
public class ServerManager
{
    private static WebApplication? _host;

    public static void RunServer(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
        builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        _host = builder.Build();
        if (_host.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            _host.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            _host.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            _host.UseHsts();
        }
        _host.UseHttpsRedirection();
        _host.UseStaticFiles();
        _host.UseRouting();
        _host.MapBlazorHub();
        _host.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        _host.Start();
    }

    public static void StopServer()
    {
        _host?.DisposeAsync();
    }
```

The main application has a reference to the Blazor project and calls RunServer on startup
and StopServer on exit. The WebView address is set to https://localhost:7012.

This approach worked fine in WPF but it seems that the server is not correctly started in Avalonia. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an open source (MIT licensed) Avalonia wrapper around winforms BlazorWebView that enables creating hybrid blazor/avalonia applications. There's a demo project included in the solution, see [here](https://github.com/jpmikkers/Baksteen.Avalonia.Blazor) . Note that my goal is ultimately to have a cross platform BlazorWebView, but it is Windows only for now.